# Можно ли обойтись без скобок в выделенном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

> Что же важно для прекрасной и могущественной герцогини? Для молодой
>   супруги и матери, которой доведётся пережить большинство своих детей?
>   Только пятеро из одиннадцати достигнут двадцатилетия. **И самые
>   драгоценные мальчишки – двое старших, один любимец отца, второй
>   баловень матери, повздорят между собой…**

Так пойдёт:

*И самые драгоценные мальчишки, двое старших – один любимец отца, второй баловень матери – повздорят между собой…*

Comment: Интересно, почему именно двадцатилетия? В те времена совершеннолетие наступало в 20 лет?

Comment: Спасибо, это надо проверять. *У Элеоноры и Козимо было 11 детей, включая 5 сыновей, достигших совершеннолетия. До этого династии Медичи угрожало угасание из-за отсутствия наследников.

Мария (1540 — 1557) /
Франческо (1541 — 1587), великий герцог Тосканский /
Изабелла (1542 — 1576), в браке с Паоло Джордано Орсини /
Джованни (1543 — 1562), кардинал /
Лукреция (1545 — 1561), герцогиня Феррарская и Моденская / 
Пьетро (1546 — 1547) /
Гарсия (1547 — 1562) /
Антонио (1548)
Фердинандо (1549 — 1609), кардинал, затем великий герцог Тосканский /
Анна (1553) /
Пьетро (1554 — 1604)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Без скобок придётся менять порядок слов, чтобы пристроить парочку тире (их не дают поставить тире при вставке) - без них странно воспринимаются числительные: а "первый баловень матери" был более покладист? "Один" естественнее сочетать в паре  с "другим" ("первый" - со "вторым").

> И повздорят между собой самые драгоценные мальчишки, двое старших:
>   один - любимец отца, *другой* - баловень матери.

Comment: Кроме того, что хорошо "легли" знаки препинания, есть дополнительный еффект: "**и**  повздорят" — акценты расставлены лучше, чем "**и**  самые драгоценные мальчишки". При авторском порядке слов лучше было бы "**а** самые драгоценные мальчишки"